# ¿Como intersectar dos array y eliminar sus valores iguales?

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos array diferentes en jQuery:

```
a = {1, 5, 3, 4}
b = {1, 4}
```

Primero obtenner los valores interceptados, serían `1`, `4`. Luego eliminar los valores interceptados en en el array `a`, quedaría así:

```
a = {5, 3}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola, los arrays en JavaScript se usan con corchetes, no con llaves, esas asignaciones no deberían funcionar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerando el comentario de @César, los arreglos no usan llaves sino corchetes.

Puedes usar [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter), de JavaScript puro, ejemplo:

```js
var a = [1, 5, 3, 4],
    b = [1, 4]

var result = a.filter(function(e) {
    return b.indexOf(e) == -1
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```